# Form field quantity up/down buttons, don't allow negative numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, input

http://jsfiddle.net/KYDPd

Is there a way to make the minimum number be 0, and not allow the user to go below 0 when clicking down?

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="0" />
  <input type="button" value="up" onclick="this.form.name.value++;" >
  <input type="button" value="down" onclick="this.form.name.value--;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably put this JavaScript in a [function](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="0" />
    <input type="button" value="up" onclick="this.form.name.value++;" >
    <input type="button" value="down" onclick="if(this.form.name.value>0)this.form.name.value--;">
</form>
```

---

**Additional Answer** with functions.

```
<script>

function ud_find_text(self) {
    var children = self.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
            return children[i];
        }
    }
}

function ud_inc(self) {
    var text = ud_find_text(self);
    text.value++;
}

function ud_dec(self) {
    var text = ud_find_text(self);
    if (text.value > 0) text.value--;
}

</script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="0" />
  <input type="button" value="up" onclick="ud_inc(this)" >
  <input type="button" value="down" onclick="ud_dec(this)">
</form>
```

Comment: This is probably the best one as I need this to repeat about 200 times within the form. Repeating the function I think would be overboard on the markup.

Comment: @deflime I have added to the answer showing how you could do it with functions. You define the functions once and then use them over and over again for each field. Note that it assumes that the field to be changed is always a text field!

Comment: @deflime Also: You can make the code a lot shorter with jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

If separate buttons are not necessary and HTML5 is an option you could just use this:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" min="0" name="name" value="0" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.  Check what the value is before you allow each operation.  Also added an onchange to the text input to inforce your minimum 0 requirement.  Agree with other answer that this should be in a function though.

http://jsfiddle.net/xqV6V/1/

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="0" onchange="if(this.value<0){this.value=0;}" />
    <input type="button" value="up" onclick="if(this.form.name.value>=0){this.form.name.value++;}" >
    <input type="button" value="down" onclick="if(this.form.name.value>0){this.form.name.value--};">
</form>
```

Comment: Can I accept two answers :)? The onchange addition is great. Not really concerned about people manually putting in a negative number but a nice addition nonetheless.